# "Object doesn't support this property or method" with jQuery Gmap plugin in all browser

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-plugins

I'm using jQuery plug-in for Google Map and it is getting intialized properly . however post initialization, any subsequent call of method `$('#map_canvas').gmap(...)` giving me below error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Code:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'MarkerClusterer')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you be calling gMap instead?

Comment: i got the reason , it is happening in IE only . and the reason is in "markerclusterer.min.js" folowing content is present . <H1>Servlet has become temporarily unavailable for service</H1><BR><H3></H3><BR><I>IBM WebSphere Application Server</I>